# How to retrieve email body of outgoing mail in apple mail using applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, apple-mail

How can i retrieve email body, recipient email address, subject etc of outgoing mail.

thanks for any help.

**EDIT:-**
I have added one custom button in outgoing mail toolbar see image.

[image]

And the functionality of that button is send mail and save all mail detail on my server also so how can i get that detail like,
both email addresses "To"="test@gmail.com" and "cc"="test2@gmail.com", subject="My subject" , and email body="My email body"

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: do you need ALL of your outgoing emails details? Sorted in which order? Or do you just need a single email? How do we know which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through this apple script you can retrieve mail content so please try it.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        set _Contents to {}
        set _contentDetail to {}
        set the _contentDetail to entire contents of UI element 1 of scroll area 3 of window 1
        repeat with _value in _contentDetail
            set str to ""
            if class of _value is static text then
                set str to value of _value
            end if
            set str to str & return
            set _Contents to _Contents & str

        end repeat
        return get _Contents as string
    end tell
end tell
```